# Run the same android emulator on Ubuntu with files taken from Windows 10 Android Studio installation?

Tags: android-studio, emulator, ubuntu-22.04

How can I open the emulator which was installed on Windows 10 with Android Studio in Ubuntu 22?
Is there a way to share the emulator data or at least its HDDs?
Or may be these emulator files are importable?

```
/media/Usename/New Volume/Usename/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator.exe
```

I have Android Studio installed on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.
And I used the Cold boot command line feature while running the emulator on Windows 10 without using the IDE itself.